# How to create dynamic function with unsure parameters in C# Emit

Tags: c#, reflection.emit, ilgenerator

I want to create dynamic function in my project, but the number of function parameters is not sure,maybe two,maybe three or more,and then i want to run a static function already in the project,the static function accept some parameters,so,how could i do it with emit? and the most important is how to deal the parameters?

My dynamic function demo

```
public static void UDFCreate(string name, string type,List<string> paramList, string APIID)
{
            Type[] types = new Type[paramList.Count];
            foreach (string param in paramList)
            {
                int index = paramList.IndexOf(param);
                types[index] = typeof(double);
            }
            
            DynamicMethod mult = new DynamicMethod(name, typeof(double), types, typeof(UDFGenerator));
            ILGenerator il = mult.GetILGenerator();
            il.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_0);//
            il.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_1);// 
            il.Emit(OpCodes.Add);// 
            il.Emit(OpCodes.Ret);// 
            List<Delegate> delegates = new List<Delegate>();
            delegates.Add(mult.CreateDelegate(typeof(Func<double, double, double>)));
            // 
            ExcelFunctionAttribute att = new ExcelFunctionAttribute();
            att.Name = name;
            att.Description = "A function to multiply two numbers";
    
            List<object> funcAttribs = new List<object>();
            funcAttribs.Add(att);
            // 
            ExcelArgumentAttribute atta1 = new ExcelArgumentAttribute();
            atta1.Description = "is the first number";
    
            ExcelArgumentAttribute atta2 = new ExcelArgumentAttribute();
            atta2.Description = "is the second number";
            List<object> argAttribs = new List<object>();
            argAttribs.Add(atta1);
            argAttribs.Add(atta2);
    
            List<List<object>> argAttribsList = new List<List<object>>();
            argAttribsList.Add(argAttribs);
            try
            {
                // 
                ExcelIntegration.RegisterDelegates(delegates, funcAttribs, argAttribsList);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }
```

My static function struct, only the *paramList* need create in runtime,others can get by*UDFCreate*

```
private static async void GetApiResult(string id, string type, List<string> paramNameList, params string[] paramList)
```

---

After two days later
Thanks @JeremyLakeman very much,that really helpful.And then I coding like this

```
private static void EmitTwo(ILGenerator il, string type, List<string> paramList, string APIID)
        {
            // Stores the APIID in a local variable with index 0
            il.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_0); // this line is must
            il.Emit(OpCodes.Ldfld, APIID);
            il.Emit(OpCodes.Stloc_0);
            // Stores the type in a local variable with index 1
            il.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_0);
            il.Emit(OpCodes.Ldfld, type);
            il.Emit(OpCodes.Stloc_1);
            // Create an array of the same size as the paramList
            il.Emit(OpCodes.Ldc_I4, paramList.Count);
            il.Emit(OpCodes.Newarr, typeof(object));
            foreach (var param in paramList)
            {
                int index = paramList.IndexOf(param);
                // Replaces the value of the array with an input parameter, subscript should starts at 1
                il.Emit(OpCodes.Dup);
                il.Emit(OpCodes.Ldc_I4, index);
                il.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_S, index + 1);
                il.Emit(OpCodes.Stelem_Ref);
            }
            il.Emit(OpCodes.Stloc_2);
            il.Emit(OpCodes.Ldloc_0);
            il.Emit(OpCodes.Ldloc_1);
            il.Emit(OpCodes.Ldloc_2);
            il.Emit(OpCodes.Call, "GetApiResult");
            il.Emit(OpCodes.Ldstr, "LOADING");
            il.Emit(OpCodes.Ret);
        }
```

But it cant work fine,i got the errors in `il.Emit(OpCodes.Ldfld, APIID);`and in `il.Emit(OpCodes.Call, "GetApiResult");`.I have tried, but i dont known how to deal that,could you help to fix that?
My goal is seems like this[sample](https://sharplab.io/#v2:C4LglgNgPgAgTARgLACgYGYAE9MGEDeqmx2WAysAE5gB2A5pgCaOYC8mARDQIYC2AphwDcREhkwVq9TMGBtOwAJ4AHQSJQlS2BAAYZ/AM7AAFAHkARgCt+AYzncANJgvW7mcwEpCGzWN1N5ZnVfPz05dllgkMwAeytbYABtAF1MA3T5Gn4Ad1j4uxTvaN9HUWLiczLfAF8okOUpE2YHWQd0gw863xh/A3kOABlTAEEAEQBJADkAcWEqzRgAdjSu6qqqhrAAN25gfmwADmwAFkxNmhMevQMEByu0uCcXBJTMCA6i6MlaBkpDeRuAGoDHAupoAGYxP7cGwAC2MO0ob0wtDeH3m0T+fUB7CxADoACoxb70YydDHENY+SkkVDVIA)

Comment: So instead of `Ldarg_0` you want `Ldarg` ? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.reflection.emit.opcodes.ldarg?view=net-6.0

Comment: @JeremyLakeman And then?if i emit Ldarg,how could i run the static function?

Comment: Maybe you should start with a disassembled example of what you are trying to achieve. eg https://sharplab.io/#v2:C4LglgNgPgAgTARgLACgYGYAE9MGFMDeqmJ2WMCAbNgCyYBiA9owBRgB2wmAhgE4DmCADTYEABh4C4IgCLdgAUwAqYALYLJ/dCIDyAIwBWCgMZc+/GiIiN2/TQFYAlAQC+xUhlHUYdALJtOTWFRCXNpTDlFFXVNbUx9I1NNS0xrWwdHQndSUiZWc2CwkXM48xTzJwBubMw3FBcgA

Comment: @JeremyLakeman Thank you very much,and i need your help again,please

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.reflection.emit.opcodes.ldfld?view=net-6.0 "The object's field is specified by a metadata token that must refer to a field member. " You need to locate the `FieldInfo` for the field somehow. While you've posted your attempt a calling `.Emit` you haven't really explained what you are trying to achieve. Try including an example C# method with the behaviour you are trying to achieve.

Comment: Finally,my purpose is like this code, create a function accept two object type parameters, then create two local variables with default string values, and then create third local array variable to store the parameters value.In the last, call a async function with all of above there local variables, before the async function run i need to return a string.

Comment: https://sharplab.io/#v2:C4LglgNgPgAgTARgLACgYGYAE9MGEDeqmx2WMCADJsAKYDOwAFAPIBGAVjQMbCYCGAGkxtOPTKwCUhFCVnZKmACaYAvJgBEAOz4BbGuoDcROcXJVea9cACeAB31GZJzAHsO3YAG0Aupjr/VTE0aAHdXdx4faWc5QWMY4lZ4uQBfRxjbACcwTSZFAWABfzoJdOczP0D1ABlmAEEAEQBJADkAcUNk2RgAdj8y4hTk5KywADc+WmwADmwAFkxR3MYKugQBVbghEQ8fTAgS6OcAZWBszQBzTEz6QLWAajo4AbkAMxcbvi4AC0YJzP2mBy+0OXWcNzomHuaghADoACouU7nC6MUpgwbJFIkVApIA=

Answer (score 0):

Simplifying your example (from comments), you want to generate a method like;

```cs
public string test(Object a, Object b){
    print("name","type",new object[]{
        a,
        b
    });
    return "LOADING";
}
```

Which would result in [IL](https://sharplab.io/#v2:C4LglgNgPgAgTARgLACgYGYAE9MGEDeqmx2WMCADJsAKYDOwAFAPIBGAVjQMbCYCGAGkxtOPTKwCUhFCVmYADgCcwAOyYAiFXwC2NdQPXAAnvL0CVNAO6YA9h27AA2gF1pc9/wFEPs1t/cAvhIA3P5yMADsmOoAMswAggAiAJIAcgDi6qEyJAFhYUpgAG58tNgALArKaozkVHQIAnWYdHBCIg4umBB0Uph5KAFAA) similar to;

```
IL_0000: ldarg.0
IL_0001: ldstr "name"
IL_0006: ldstr "type"
IL_000b: ldc.i4.2 // array size
IL_000c: newarr [System.Runtime]System.Object
IL_0011: dup
IL_0012: ldc.i4.0 // array index 0
IL_0013: ldarg.1  // argument value
IL_0014: stelem.ref
IL_0015: dup
IL_0016: ldc.i4.1 // array index 1
IL_0017: ldarg.2  // argument value
IL_0018: stelem.ref
IL_0019: call instance void C::print(string, string, object[])
IL_001e: ldstr "LOADING"
IL_0023: ret
```

I don't have any actual experience with using `il.Emit`, but I would suggest you start by trying to output that method exactly. Then turn the array creation into a loop. Modifying the lines above which have comments, into the similar `ldc.i4` / `ldarg` op codes which allow you to specify an explicit `int` or argument value.

Comment: `il.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_0);
il.Emit(OpCodes.Ldstr, APIID);
il.Emit(OpCodes.Ldstr, type);
il.Emit(OpCodes.Ldc_I4, paramList.Count);
il.Emit(OpCodes.Newarr, typeof(object));
foreach (var param in paramList)
{
int index = paramList.IndexOf(param);
il.Emit(OpCodes.Dup);
il.Emit(OpCodes.Ldc_I4, index);
il.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_S, index +1);
il.Emit(OpCodes.Stelem_Ref);
} 
MethodInfo mi = typeof(UDFGenerator).GetMethod("GetApiResult", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Static);
il.Emit(OpCodes.Call, mi);
il.Emit(OpCodes.Ldstr, "LOADING");
il.Emit(OpCodes.Ret);`

Comment: This is my `Emit` code and it worked in `TypeBuilder.DefineMethod` but not `DynamicMethod`